# can you version-control Java Web Dynpro projects with Git and, if yes, what do you have to consider?

Tags: java, git, webdynpro

we have a small SAP server with a Web Dynpro Java stack. At the moment, each one of us has a local copy of the corresponding project. Changes from one person have to be merged with another person's changes by hand.

We have not yet tried using Git before. However, some of my colleagues have tried SVN and found that automatically generated files are a huge problem. Also, view files seem to cause inconsistencies, so that one has to clean and rebuild the Java Web Dynpro project several times in order to get it to work again.

This all seems not really comfortable, at least we backed off from using SVN. Personally I like Git more anyways.

Is there any best practice out there how to use Git to version-control Java Web Dynpro projects, so that collaboration works in a somewhat reliable way?

All the best,
Michael

Comment: Can you tell me more about the automatically generated files?  Are these files something which should be versioned?  It sounds as though they should not.  Once we answer this question, we can address what might be needed from Git to solve your use case.

Comment: I am not entirely sure where the trouble would start (I could just try out Git, though, to tell you). There are several webdynpro-related files like .wdcomponent, .wdinterface and the like. Also, there is a folder with "gen_wdp", where mainly Java classes lie that are generated, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Git on prod project, there is my `.gitignore` file:

```
bin/
gen/
gen_ddic/
gen_wdp/
gen_cmi/
dependencies.properties
.project
.classpath
.settings/
```

a tips: one man on one WebDynpro Component is easy for git.

Comment: we are a small team of 2-4 people at max. Would this change anything here? Just ignoring all the generated files is interesting... we still need to build a lot, then

Comment: `.dcdef` is the important dependencies file on project directory, and all source on `src` directory.

Comment: there is no .dcdef file in my project directory, though

Comment: oh, maybe you are use NetWeaver2004s version.

Comment: how do I find out? It says NetWeaver 7.1 CE und build ID starting with 2014

Comment: there is a lot of source code in gen_wdp in our project